# Intro Page for 5 Seconds after the default.png file and before the MainWindow.nib

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, iphone-sdk-3.1

I had created a project where the `default.png` sleeps for 3 seconds and then the `MainWindow.xib` is loaded I wanted to create a new `IntroPageViewController.xib` before the `FirstPageViewController.xib` loads . I wanted to put some text in the IntroPage which loads for 10 seconds and has a skip button .
I already created the `FirstPageViewController.xib` , now I want to load `IntroPageViewController.xib` in `applicationdidfinishlaunching` .

I tried to make changes in the `FirstPageAppDelegate.h` and .m but still the `FirstPageViewController.xib` loads and if I make changes to `info.plist` to load `IntroPageViewController.xib` or `IntroPageViewController` the application crashes .
Help needed please .

Thanks a ton in advance :)

Regards,
Coder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading the IntroPageViewController.xib ahead of the FirstPageViewController.xib manually, try this:

- When the FirstPage loads, show the
  IntroPage view on top of it.
- After a delay or when skip button is
  pressed, remove the IntroPage.

Here's how:

Make an IntroPageViewController with corresponding xib file.
In Xcode, setup a button and an action method for that button.

```
// in your .h file.   

@interface IntroViewController : UIViewController {
    UIButton *skipButton;
}  

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *skipButton;

-(IBAction)skipPressed;

@end  

// in the .m file  

-(IBAction)skipPressed {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview]; // this removes intro screen from the screen, leaving you FirstView
}

// put this in the viewDidLoad method
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSelector:@selector(skipPressed) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}

// add these in FirstViewController.m  

#import "IntroViewController.h"  

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    IntroViewController *introViewController = [[IntroViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IntroViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.view addSubview:introViewController.view];
    [introViewController release]; // this removes your IntroScreen from memory once it disappears offscreen
}
```

Now the next step is to open IntroViewController.xib in Interface Builder and drag a UIButton to the view, set its title to 'Skip'.

Connect the button to the **skipPressed** action and connect File's Owner to the button.

Go back to Xcode and **Build and Run** to test it. If all is well, your IntroView should be visible at launch time for 5 seconds or until you touch the Skip button.

Answer (score 0):

use nstimer to create some timer. The corresponding action will be executed after 10 sec or when skip button will be pressed.

Comment: Thanks for that ... Even if I don't want a timer just the Skip Button I am having trouble with loading the IntroPageViewController.xib first ..
Instead the FirstViewController.xib gets loaded which I don't want .